# To get users in azure active directory

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph API calls to get the details of all users in the organization.

```
function string getusers(){
        var client1 = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
        var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request1.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request1.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        request1.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no");
        IRestResponse response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
        return response1.Content.toString();
}
```

I am using this API call but it is returning an error related to authentication:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "16a2e8d3-a93d-4197-9ef9-8b67a705f0e5",
            "date": "2018-02-17T19:51:46"
        }
    }
}
```

But as I change

```
var client1 = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
```

to

```
var client1 = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
```

Then it returns all details about currently logged in user.

It is really complex for me to solve it without any help or reference.

Comment: Multiple reasons why it might happen. Check you have added a required permission for Microsoft Graph API to read users. Then make sure you *grant* that permission. Then, make sure you specify `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` when requesting the access token.

Comment: As you suggested to add permission to read users for Microsoft Graph Api, Does it mean the same as I have given permission to all user to read users in Azure?

Comment: Umm, not really? To do that, you need to find your app, go to Required permissions, and then add MS Graph API there (with the scopes you need selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have requested the `user.read` scope. This will allow you to read the current user's profile (`/me`) but not other user's within the tenant (`/users`).

You need to also request the [`User.ReadBasic.All`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) to your authentication request. This will allow you to read basic profile information for any user in the tenant.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, it make sense but I don't know how to use it.
Could you please edit my code by adding codes for requesting User.ReadBasic.All.

It will be really helpful for me

Thanks

Comment: You need to request this when you retrieve your token or pre-define it your app registration.